# How to add images to a header in a PrimeFaces Dialog?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

How to add a image '(?)' beside the Header Menu.and same time I need to add tooltip for it. Here is my HTML code -

```
<p:dialog id="ABC"
          widgetVar="ABC"
          header="HEader Menu "
          dynamic="true" showEffect="clip"
          closable="true"
          onShow="checkEscape()"
          height="150"
          width="500"
          resizable="true">

    <ui:include src="/../../xyz.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="" value="#/"/>
        <ui:param name="" value="#"/>
    </ui:include>
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 4):

You will have to add a custom `facet` similar to

```
<p:dialog>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <img src="..." title="Tooltip"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:dialog>
```